# how to display chart data as html table chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatable, chart.js

I would like to know how to view chart data as html table on button click in chartjs.
I have implemented the line chart using chartjs , 
xaxis represents the color 
yaxis represents votes and points

Working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/ehqrL20o/
I want to display chart as table

```
Color | # of Votes | # of Points
Red     12           7
Blue    19           11
... and so on
```

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
//html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not clear, please provide more info or sandbox sample.

Comment: @Alex thanks for reply, I want to display chart data as html table,

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question and fiddle

Comment: What's the problem with @SciFiThief answer? what do you mean by "chart as table"?please draw your desired result and attach to question. could help to clarify exactly  what do you intend

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify what in your chart data could be represented as columns and rows in the table. If you named your x-axis, you could represent the chart data like this:

```
Color | # of Votes | # of Points
Red     12           7
Blue    19           11
... and so on
```

Also, chart data can be represented as a crosstab which is a more direct representation (since datapoint lies where x and y intersects):

```
             | Red | Blue | ... and so on
# of Votes     12    19
# of Points    7     11
```

Here's the example of how you can convert the chart data to crosstab: https://jsfiddle.net/tara5/cjvuphkL/

Comment: thanks for reply, I have updated my question and added fiddle link

Comment: I see that you provided a fiddle link, but still, it doesn't have any code where you try to convert chart data to the table. Also, you could easily modify my example with the crosstab to a table (it is basically a table). You just need to swap rows and columns, and name the first column 'Colors'. The example has all the necessary code.